# Is there any possibility to add a source term to Ansys Mechanical?

Tags: simulation, user-defined-functions, ansys

I am trying to do a transient thermal simulation in Ansys mechanical. To get a more appropriate simulation I want to "add" a source term. In special I want to add a reduction extent to my equation, which is temperature dependent.

I tried to do this with APDL commands but I am not very familiar with this programming language nor with the routines in Ansys.

Here is the "pseudo-code" I thought about so far:

```
! ############################################
! Getting values and material data
! ############################################

*GET, NumberOfMeshElements, VOLU, 0, COUNT, , Body 1, ! Number of Elements in Body 1
*GET, TimeStepSize, ACTIVE, 0, SOLU, DTIME

*SET, CeriaAmount, 1000 ! in mol 
*SET, ReductionEnthalpy, 500 ! in kJ/mol O (

*SET, OxygenPartialPressure, 100 ! Setting oxygen partial pressure
*SET, Temperature, TEMP ! Setting Temperature as a variable

*SET, ReductionExtent, 0 ! previous reduction extent 

! ############################################
! Calculation of Source Term
! ############################################

! Begin of Loop for each time step

*DO, t, 0, 10, TimeStepSize ! solve together with transient thermal analysis (convection, radiation, conduction) 

ReductionExtent = 0.35 * EXP(Temperature) ! goal: storing of previous (t-1) value for later calculation of Rate of Change

! Begin of Loop for each element

*DO, i, 1, NumberOfMeshElements, 1 ! needed for each mesh element because each mesh element has a different temperature

*GET, MeshElementVolume, VOLU, i, VOLU, , Body 1,
ReductionExtentRateOfChange = ReductionExtent(t-1)- ReductionExtent(i) / TimeStepSize

S_reaction = - CeriaAmount / MeshElementVolume * ReductionEnthalpy * ReductionExtentRateOfChange ! usally a source term
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but can you accomplish the source through the material model? Something akin to VM104 in the verification manual?
Or do you want to influence a boundary condition based on a temperature? Something like a PID controller?

Comment: Hello, I want to calculate the reduction extent for a chemical reaction. This extent is depending on temperature. Normally this is done together with the energy equation PDE. In Ansys fluent one could add user defined functions but in my case I use the Mechanical simulation model because the temperature modelling is easier with this.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a way to generate heat depending on a nodal temperature:

https://forum.ansys.com/discussion/1695/heat-generation

If you need this method as APDL you can prototype your solution in the workbench and than lookup the APDL commands in the generated ds.dat.

**APDL for the internal heat generation**

You can either fit the Arrehnius equation to the polynom Property = C0 + C1(T) + C2(T)^2 + C3(T)^3 + C4(T)^4 and put that as your material model with
`MP, QRATE, MATNUMBER, C0, C1, C2, C3, C4`  or reference to a table name (C0 = %QRATETABLE%) created by

```
*DIM,QRATETABLE,TABLE,5,,,TEMP                     !  Define QRATE with TEMP 
                                                   !              primary variable
QRATETABLE(1,0)=0.,50.,100.,150.,200.              ! Assign temperature values
QRATETABLE(1,1)=1,2,3,4,5                  ! Assign heat generation values !!! I am using dummy values !!!!

MP,QRATE, MATNUMBER,%QRATETABLE%                   ! Input QRATE on the MP command
```

Comment: Hello (sorry for the late answer). If it cant be done with Ansys mechanical I maybe try to do this with Ansys fluent but the thermal simulation itself works totally fine in Ansys mechanical - so it would be a bit of a annoyance to switch the tools... However: Maybe using Ansys user programmable features (UDF) is a solution but I think its not easy and I have only 2 months left...

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help. This is an interesting point. However I think that it doesn not match my problem very good. Let me describe my problem in different words: I want to know two things. 1) the reduction extent - e.g. how much is created in each time step. For this I want to use an equation based on the Arrhenius equation for chemical reactions. 
2) I want to know the heat sink, e.g. how much enegry is "lost" due to the chemical reaction. 

If your solution fits to my problem and I didnt understand it I am very sorry!

Comment: Furthermore the MASS71 method states "The element may be used in a transient thermal analysis to represent a body having thermal capacitance capability but negligible internal thermal resistance, that is, no significant temperature gradients within the body." - in my case the material has a very bad conductivity and therefore a high gradient... I dont know if the MASS71 method can be used in this case

Comment: Sorry, I had to delete a previous comment of mine since I figured something out. What do you think about the fact that the MASS71 method is not recommended for elements with a high temperature gradient?

Comment: And, if I got the above mentioned post right, one could implement this MASS71 method with the so named "thermal point mass". What I recognized in this setup is that I was not able to fit it to the desired equation and also I could not use a negative magnitude.

Comment: Can you define a negative slope when you use a **table** instead of the polynom? If not it could mean that my solution does not fit to your problem. Do you get an error which states something like that?

Comment: I think a high temperature gradient is a mesh size issue: With a fine enough mesh your can resolve the gradients.

Comment: That means you must use enough MASS71-elements so that the gradient inside each element is neglible.